# Failure 1 (unrecognized token: "1295980589.jpg") on 0x2a6530

Tags: android, database, sqlite

this is the error:

```
09-28 17:48:03.830: ERROR/Database(1485): Failure 1 (unrecognized token: "1295980589.jpg") on 0x2a6530 when preparing 'INSERT INTO bookmarks (id, title, image1File) VALUES (2014, 'Hilton Craigendarroch, '1295980589.jpg')'.
```

this is the code:

```
this.db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + CMSConstants.BOOKMARKS + " (" + CMSConstants.ID + ", " + CMSConstants.TITLE + ", " + CMSConstants.IMAGE1_FILE + ") VALUES (" + id + ", '" + title + ", '" + image + "')");
```

where is the problem?
Hope someone can help me....

Thanx
newone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the closing single quote on the title. What you thought was the opening quote for the image name is the closing quote for the title. Try this:

```
this.db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "
    + CMSConstants.BOOKMARKS
    + " ("
    + CMSConstants.ID
    + ", "
    + CMSConstants.TITLE
    + ", "
    + CMSConstants.IMAGE1_FILE
    + ") VALUES ("
    + id
    + ", '"
    + title
    + "', '" // <-- Note ' before ,
    + image
    + "')");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + CMSConstants.BOOKMARKS + " (" + CMSConstants.ID + ", " + CMSConstants.TITLE + ", " + CMSConstants.IMAGE1_FILE + ") VALUES (" + id + ", '" + title + "', '" + image + "')");
```

try this, you forgot one "'"

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the closing single quote on the title

Try this

```
this.db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + CMSConstants.BOOKMARKS + " (" + CMSConstants.ID + ", " + CMSConstants.TITLE + ", " + CMSConstants.IMAGE1_FILE + ") VALUES (" + id + ", '" + title + "', '" + image + "')");
```